# scp copy has error "ambiguous target"

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssh, scp

I try to copy files from a linux (ubuntu) machine to an external hard drive mounted on a mac but got an error message :

```
scp: ambiguous target
```

What I did is, I'm on a mac, ssh to the linux machine where files are. Then use the following command :

```
scp fileToCopy myMacUser@myMacMachine:/Volumes/MyExternalDrive/targetDirectory
```

What did I do wrong ? What is the good command to use in this case ?

Comment: Happened to me when I had an extra param (`-t`; a remnant from a previous `ssh` command) in the arg list; apparently it is not supported by `scp` but the error I got was `ambiguous target` :(

Answer (score 140, accepted):

If you have white space in a path, you have to escape the characters by using double backslashes `\\` and enclosing the entire path in quotes:

```
scp myfile.txt user@192.168.1.100:"/file\\ path\\ with\\ spaces/myfile.txt"
```

Comment: yes, that is it ! I first tried with double \\ but didn't work and then I tried adding " " around my path with \\. That does the job. Thanks.

Comment: I have to look this up every time! the error message should say you have to escape spaces 3 times...

Comment: Wrapping the remote path in quotes was key for me

Comment: Single quotes and single backslashes works just as well.

Comment: Triple backslashes without quotes works also.

Comment: Double quotes in single qoutes without escaping spaces also work (`scp myfile.txt user@192.168.1.100:'"/file path with spaces/myfile.txt"'`). In fact you must escape the filename twice: first time from the local shell, and second time from the remote one.

Comment: Per @sam452 key is to wrap ONLY THE REMOTE TARGET in quotes.  Wrapping the local file kept giving me "no such file or directory" errors

Comment: You can also single-escape the whitespace and use single quotes, like `scp file.txt remotehost:'/dir\ with\ spaces'`

Answer (score 20):

I found that two sets of quotes worked for me, around the target location. Double quotes outside, and single quotes inside the double quotes. For example:

```
scp "my local file.txt" user@192.168.1.100:"'/folder/my spacey folder name/'"
```

The outside set of quotes are for the local shell, and the inside quotes are for the remote shell.  Thanks to @mik for the suggestion in comments.

Comment: I used this in a script, that accepts a folder to recursively copy, like so: `scp -r "$*" SOME_HOST:"'$*'"`

Comment: This is much nicer than escaping spaces. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes so that spaces won't be misinterpreted.
Instead of doing `scp file Server:/folder\ location/` you should do `scp file "Server:/folder\ location/"`