# scp: ambiguous target error, with quotes, escape characters in Windows 10

Tags: command-line, ssh, scp

Getting scp: ambiguous target while transferring file to white spaced folder name in Windows 10 (both pc). I already tried solutions mentioned in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1022976/scp-copy-has-error-ambiguous-target) and also tried another [solution on different question](https://superuser.com/questions/1310766/scp-from-remote-linux-to-local-windows-with-spaces-in-local-path).

following commands are already tried,

1. `scp -i "key" test.txt "user@host:E:New\\ folder"`,
2. `scp -i "key" test.txt user@host:"E:New folder"`,
3. `scp -i "key" test.txt user@host:"'E:New folder'"`,
4. `scp -i "key" test.txt "user@host:'E:New folder'"`,
5. `scp -i "key" test.txt user@host:"E:New\ folder"`

Still getting **ambiguous target**. Is there any mistake? how to overcome this ?

Comment: Got invalid 'user invalid username error

Comment: So the local machine is Windows and the remote machine is Windows? It's not exactly clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the file this way when the folder name is spaced

```
sshpass -p pass scp -r 32.zip user@host:'"C:\\New folder\\"'
```

Another way is this

```
sshpass -p pass scp -r 32.zip user@host:C:\\New\\\ folder\\
```

use \\\ Instead of space